# Reading and writing from and to different files in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read the commands from "command.txt" file and want to redirect the output of this commands to "output.txt", contents of command.txt

```
ps -a
free
```

So far I came up with this code which for certain reason is not good and fails to execute.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file, open('command.txt', 'r') as in_file:
     for line in in_file:
         output = subprocess.Popen(line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         print output
         out_file.write(output)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Error:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7/Users/PythonTutorials/subprocess1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/shandeepkm/PythonTutorials/subprocess1.py", line 9, in <module>
   output = subprocess.Popen(line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone please suggest appropriate python code for this task.

Comment: " I came up with this code which for certain reason is not good" -- which reason is that? "and fails to execute" -- how does it fail?

Comment: @ShandeepMurugasamy Ok, I found the answer to your updated problem. I can now run your code to completion. See my revised solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1: Execute line by line

You can redirect to a file using the `stdout` parameter of `Popen`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as outfile, open('command.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        command = shlex.split(line)
        if not command:
            continue  # Skip blank lines
        try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=outfile)
            process.wait()
        except OSError:
            outfile.write('COMMAND ERROR: {}'.format(line))
```

In the code above, you redirect the output by pointing `stdout` to the output file's handle, no printing is needed. The code also guard against bad commands

## Solution 2: Call the shell

If you are running under Linux or Mac, the following solution is simpler: by calling bash to execute the whole command.txt file and record the stdout and stderr. This should work under windows with `cmd -c`, but I don't have a Windows machine to try.

```
import subprocess

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    command = ['bash', 'command.txt']
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)
    process.wait()
```

Comment: So in the above code, `command = shlex.split(line)` would return ['ps', '-a'] and ['free']. And if in line `process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=outfile, stderr=outfile)`, these 2 commands would be executed simultaneously right?

Comment: Since we are reading the file one line at the time (first solution), we execute them one at a time, not simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

I see two errors.

First, you have "command.txt" as the first line in your file. That definitely won't execute as a subprocess.

Also, your line

```
out_file.write(output)
```

needs to be tabbed under the `for` loop.

---

Now for the updated question:

The [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) constructor needs to take an array for the args. So instead of

```
'ps -a'
```

you need to pass

```
['ps', '-a']
```

Also, what gets returned from `Popen` isn't text. So altogether you need:

```
args = shlex.split(line)
output = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but still getting the above errors.

Comment: @ShandeepMurugasamy When you say you "tried that", you mean you removed "command.txt" from your file?

Comment: On windows, I had to add shell = True. (Though this is due to me using specific windows shell commands, i.e. `echo`. If executing a batch file or the like, default False should be OK.

Comment: @tenwest Good point. From the above link: "The only time you need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable."